# Is it recommended to use install4j actions inside custom actions?

Tags: install4j

Today I have a simple questions, maybe. Is it recommended to use install4j standard actions inside customized actions? Let's say to use the `CopyFileAction` instead common APIs like `commons-io`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. The actions are not documented, but code completion will give you all the properties that you see in the GUI. Note that rollback will not be called for actions that are executed in that way.